# Add new objects after using "new"

Tags: c++, pointers, object, new-operator

after I call new, how can I add more objects to the pointer? (I need it for a class)
this is what I mean:

```
int *a;
a = new int;
a = new int;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this for school?  If so, have you gone over arrays in class?

Comment: That's a nice memory leak you've got there.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) or [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/).

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to practice the "new" and "delete" and templates.

Comment: `new` and `delete` are as much standard as `vector` and `list`. `new` and `delete` are not very applicable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you would use `realloc`. In C++, you would use STL's `std::vector` instead of a pointer. You could always do something ugly like:

```
int *a;
a = new int[1];
delete [] a;
a = new int[2];
```

But you'd hit a performance drop.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a contiguous buffer use vector.

```
std::vector<int> buf;
buf.push_back( 1 );
buf.push_back( 2 );
buf.push_back( 3 );

int * intbuf = &buf[0];
```

Beware this pointer could be invalidated if you add more items to your vector. You can prevent this if you want by doing this first:

```
buf.reserve( 65536 );
```

or some other number. You can still add more than 65536 items to the vector but it is guaranteed that as long as the size is less than this, &buf[0] will not change.

Given that you are not doing any of this though, you are trying to implement vector, one way to do this is not to use new at all but to use malloc to allocate the memory, thus:

```
char * buf = static_cast<char *>( malloc( BUF_SIZE ) );
```

Now you can create objects in here with placement new

```
int * intbuf = new( buf + sizeof(int) * N ) int( i );
```

When you need more space you can "realloc" your pointer. Be certain to realloc to a temporary one first to check it succeeds.

```
bufNew = static_cast< char * >( realloc( buf, newBufSize ) );
if( bufNew )
     buf = bufNew;
```

This works here because int is POD type. If the type is not POD it is not safe to realloc and simply move objects by memory, you need to move them as objects, using operator= on each one.

Now you know a bit about this, but for practical purposes you probably want to use vector.

Comment: malloc, placement new, and realloc are unnecessarily complicated for this poster.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to write your own vector class that can grow on demand. You can do this as follows:

```
int * a; // original pointer
a = new int[5]; // just five elements
```

Now to grow it to 10 elements (make a new array, copy the old contents, reclaim the old array's memory, and reassign the array pointer):

```
int * tmp = new int[10]; // a new array
memcpy (tmp, a, 5 * sizeof(int)); // copy the old items into the new array
delete [] a; // reclaim the memory from the old array
a = tmp; // reassign a to point to the new, bigger array
```

See [Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), Chapter 17.4, for description and analysis of such a "dynamic table."